# How can I specify an angular environment on ionic build?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular6, staging

The `Ionic` framework uses `Angular`.
Angular 6 defines environments in `./src/environments/environment.stage.ts` .

When building an Angular app, I can select the environment with the parameter `--env=stage` or `--configuration==stage` in Angular 6.

To build the ionic app, I use `ionic cordova build <platform>` which in the background first builds the angular app, before packing it in the Cordova framework.

How can I specify the environment aka configuration for the angular build?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add a corresponding configuration entry in angular.json at ionic-cordova-build:

```
"ionic-cordova-build": {
  "builder": "@ionic/angular-toolkit:cordova-build",
  "options": {
    "browserTarget": "app:build"
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
    },
    "staging": {
      "browserTarget": "app:build:staging"
    }
  }
},
```

```
$ ionic cordova run android --device -c staging
```

Note the difference from `-c staging` to `-- -c=staging` on ionic serve.

The configuration staging must exists under `architect.build.configurations` in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

On my hand, I created a simple bash file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

env=$1

targetFile=$PWD/src/environment/environment.ts
filePath=$PWD/src/environment/$1.environment.ts

echo REPLACING FILE ENVIRONMENT : $1
cp $filePath $targetFile
```

I added `environment.ts` in .gitignore, and I created a `dev.environment.ts` and `prod.environment.ts`.

I switch :

```
$ bash launcher.sh dev && ionic serve
```

Comment: Yes, that's simiar to what I'm doing right now. I hoped to find a more integrated way :-).

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any way to pass your Angular native parameters to an Ionic application.

But Cordova give you plenty of possibilities to manage your app like the `hooks` feature by example (read [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/)) or by passing a particular config file (see how the `--buildConfig` flag works [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/)).

I don't really know what you are trying to achieve here, but different environnement sometimes only mean passing different configuration files to your cordova build command. It is up to you to launch it the right way.

**EDIT** :

You may be looking for the `ionic cordova build --prod` command... see the full doc [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/build/)

Hope it helps a bit...

Comment: As far as I can see, `Cordova` does not know about `Angular` at all. `Ionic` builds the `Angular` app before starting `cordova build`. The `--prod` parameter of `ionic cordova build` does switch the environment / configuration of the `Angular` but I have more stages than just `development` and `prod` (`emulation`, `staging`). So I'm still looking ...